# Android go back to activity or recreate

Tags: android, button, android-activity, notifications, back

I am developing media player application in which i am showing a notification when song starts playing in a service.

Basically i am showing a list view in my first activity(being any one from Artist tab, album tab etc) and on click of an item , player screen is shown.

I have to implement a back button in my player activity, i guess i just have to do a finish() on click of it.

But in case my previous activity is destroyed and i am coming through pending intent(through notification), if i call finish() now the activity is simply destroyed. In such case i want to  recreate the previous activity.

**Example :**

Album > player screen is shown and songs starts in service with status bar notification..

Suppose i press back now and destroy all the activity.

Click on notification > Player is shown again.. if i press back now Album activity should be shown similarly for artist tab.

**So far i am just doing:**

```
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            finish();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can achieve what you need with setting the intent flags accordingly. The best introduction to these flags I found is the following

[Android Activities and Tasks series – Intent flags](http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/)

It is still a confusing subject for me yet the Android application offered along with this article is very helpful to check quickly what the different flags do.

Answer (score 1):

I thinking you must set more informations about song in Service like a album and when you press back in song activity you should chek service and give back it from Service and init album activity